# SQL - How to show duplicates across multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database which has contains the following two tables - `Departments` and `Operations`

The key values for `Departments` are:

```
DEPT_REF
DEPT_NAME
DEPT_FUNCTION
```

The key values for `Operations` are:

```
OPS_REF
OPS_NAME
DEPT_REF
```

What I need to work out is a query which will get me a list of `Operations.OPS_NAME`, `Departments.DEPT_NAME` and `Departments.DEPT_FUNCTION` where they are duplicates but it should ignore case. Ideally it should have a count as well.

For example:

`Departments`

```
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| DEPT_REF | DEPT_NAME | DEPT_FUNCTION |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| 0001     | Home      | Live here     |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| 0002     | HOME      | LIVE HERE     |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| 0003     | HOME      | Live here     |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| 0004     | work      | Work Here     |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| 0005     | Work      | Work Here     |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| 0006     | OTHER     | Other Stuff   |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
```

`Operations`

```
+---------+----------+----------+
| OPS_REF | OPS_NAME | DEPT_REF |
+---------+----------+----------+
| 000A    | OPS1     | 0001     |
+---------+----------+----------+
| 000B    | Ops1     | 0001     |
+---------+----------+----------+
| 000C    | ops1     | 0002     |
+---------+----------+----------+
| 000D    | OPS2     | 0003     |
+---------+----------+----------+
| 000E    | ops2     | 0001     |
+---------+----------+----------+
| 000F    | ops2     | 0004     |
+---------+----------+----------+
| 000G    | OPS3     | 0004     |
+---------+----------+----------+
| 000H    | OPS3     | 0005     |
+---------+----------+----------+
```

The output I am looking for would be a list of operations names, department names and department functions displayed in uppercase with a count. So from the example data I would expect to see:

```
+----------+-----------+---------------+-------+
| OPS_NAME | DEPT_NAME | DEPT_FUNCTION | COUNT |
+----------+-----------+---------------+-------+
| OPS1     | HOME      | LIVE HERE     | 3     |
+----------+-----------+---------------+-------+
| OPS2     | HOME      | LIVE HERE     | 2     |
+----------+-----------+---------------+-------+
```

Finding duplicates in a single table is no problem but I don't know where to start to do it across multiple tables which has to ignore case.

Comment: I think you're over complicating things here, the case shouldn't matter. run this code on your system and you should see that SQL considers the strings the same thing. SELECT CASE WHEN 'lower' = 'LOWER' THEN 'Same' ELSE 'Different' END

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to separate upper and lower cases of `OPS_NAME` you can use 
CAST them to binary datatype:

```
SELECT  UPPER(o.OPS_NAME) as OPS_NAME,
        UPPER(d.DEPT_NAME) as DEPT_NAME,
        UPPER(d.DEPT_FUNCTION) as DEPT_FUNCTION,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(o.OPS_NAME As BINARY)) AS [COUNT]
FROM Departments d
INNER JOIN Operations o
    ON o.DEPT_REF = d.DEPT_REF
GROUP BY o.OPS_NAME,
        d.DEPT_NAME,
        d.DEPT_FUNCTION
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(o.OPS_NAME As BINARY)) > 1
```

Output:

```
OPS_NAME    DEPT_NAME   DEPT_FUNCTION   COUNT
OPS1        HOME        LIVE HERE       3
OPS2        HOME        LIVE HERE       2
```

**EDIT**

You can also use `COUNT(DISTINCT o.OPS_NAME COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS)`
 as advised in comments. In your case will also work `COUNT(DISTINCT BINARY_CHECKSUM(o.OPS_NAME))` but it can give a duplicates in some cases.

Comment: Do you want to group by the columns' original values, or their UPPER values?

Comment: @jarlh Thanks, to your comment I realized what OP required!

Comment: `CHECKSUM` can result in duplicates, but `BINARY_CHECKSUM` can not in current case. `CAST(o.OPS_NAME As BINARY)` is a good approach to, I just choose this one.

Comment: @Y.B. add this info to my answer, thanks one more time!

Comment: Thank you. All answers appear to work, for my scenario at least, so I have up voted each of them. Marking this one as the answer.

Comment: Check this out: [Hashing Collisions](https://voiceofthedba.wordpress.com/2012/04/11/hashing-collisions/) `SELECT 'LE', BINARY_CHECKSUM('LE') UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Ou', BINARY_CHECKSUM('Ou') UNION ALL 
SELECT 'MU', BINARY_CHECKSUM('MU')`

Comment: @Y.B. quite interesting!

Answer (score 3):

ANSI SQL compliant answer (do the `UPPER()` in a derived table):

```
select OPS_NAME, DEPT_NAME, DEPT_FUNCTION, count(OPS_REF)
from
(
    SELECT UPPER(o.OPS_NAME) as OPS_NAME,
           UPPER(d.DEPT_NAME) as DEPT_NAME,
           UPPER(d.DEPT_FUNCTION) as DEPT_FUNCTION,
           o.OPS_REF as OPS_REF
    FROM Departments d
    INNER JOIN Operations o
        ON o.DEPT_REF = d.DEPT_REF
) dt
GROUP BY OPS_NAME,
         DEPT_NAME,
         DEPT_FUNCTION

HAVING count(OPS_REF) > 1
```

But I'd rather suggest another approach, define the columns to use a **case insensitive collation**! Then group by / comparisons etc will work automatically! (I.e. no need to do `UPPER()`.)

Comment: May be a bit of an uninformed question but what would be the benefit of doing it this was as apposed to the other proposed solutions? What makes it ANSI compliant?

Comment: @Zammalad, according to ANSI SQL you can only group by columns, not by expressions. So if you want to group by the UPPER-ed column values, you first have to do the UPPER in a derived table. (Also, no need to duplicate complex expressions, easier to maintain, less typing errors etc!)

Answer (score 2):

Case shouldn't be a concern. I have converted the data to uppercase for the purposes of presentation.

Test Data;

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Departments') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Departments
GO
CREATE TABLE #Departments (DEPT_REF varchar(4), DEPT_NAME varchar(5), DEPT_FUNCTION varchar(11))
INSERT INTO #Departments (DEPT_REF, DEPT_NAME, DEPT_FUNCTION)
VALUES
 ('0001','Home','Live here')
,('0002','HOME','LIVE HERE')
,('0003','HOME','Live here')
,('0004','work','Work Here')
,('0005','Work','Work Here')
,('0006','OTHER','Other Stuff')

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Operations') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Operations
GO
CREATE TABLE #Operations (OPS_REF varchar(4), OPS_NAME varchar(4), DEPT_REF varchar(4))
INSERT INTO #Operations (OPS_REF, OPS_NAME, DEPT_REF)
VALUES
 ('000A','OPS1','0001')
,('000B','Ops1','0001')
,('000C','ops1','0002')
,('000D','OPS2','0003')
,('000E','ops2','0001')
,('000F','ops2','0004')
,('000G','OPS3','0004')
,('000H','OPS3','0005')
```

Actual Query

```
SELECT 
UPPER(o.OPS_NAME) OPS_NAME
,UPPER(d.DEPT_NAME) DEPT_NAME
,UPPER(d.DEPT_FUNCTION) DEPT_FUNCTION
,COUNT(d.DEPT_NAME) COUNT
FROM #Operations o
LEFT JOIN #Departments d
ON o.DEPT_REF = d.DEPT_REF
GROUP BY o.OPS_NAME, d.DEPT_NAME, d.DEPT_FUNCTION
HAVING COUNT(d.DEPT_NAME) > 1
```

Results

```
OPS_NAME    DEPT_NAME   DEPT_FUNCTION   COUNT
OPS1        HOME        LIVE HERE       3
OPS2        HOME        LIVE HERE       2
OPS3        WORK        WORK HERE       2
```